# How to remove margin on <v-textarea>? vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a textarea and I found that it has top margin.
like this..

[image]

this is my code:

```
<v-flex d-flex xs12>
    <v-textarea
       v-model="test"
       outline
       type="text"
       color="primary"
       v-validate="{required: true}"
       data-vv-name="test"
       :error-messages="errors.collect('test')"
     > </v-textarea>
 </v-flex>
```

I tried adding `class="mt-0"` to `v-textarea` but it did not work.
Does anyone know how to remove and why I have this top margin?

I am using version 1.5.x

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Not the best practice but you can inspect elements and find which class adds the margin.
Then add custom class on textarea.

```
.your-class >>> .textarea-class-that-you-found {
    margin-top: 0
  }
```

Comment: I've inspected the field, and it seemed there's margin-top=12px set to this item (by default I guess) so I added `.v-textarea.v-text-field--enclosed textarea {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}` but it did not work.